# split strings and append by multiple conditions

Tags: python, regex, string, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe with a jobtitle-column that i want to split into separate columns. Because of the great variety of string patterns within this column, i filtered them for unique before sorting them and synthesizing the patterns to the 3 below.

My assumption is that if it can handle these 3 strings the way i want to, it will handle all the others in that dataframe, too.

**Data**

```
print(df['split_these_jobtitles'])
0  '- a a (a a), a a', '- a a (Also xxxx), a a', '- a a (a a), a a', 'a a (a, a a)', 'a a, a a', 'a a'       
1  "a a, a' a", 'a a, a 5 (a, a)', 'a a'                                                               
2  'Chair, a (a & a), a a, a', 'Chair, a, a & a-a - a -a' 'a (a a) (a, a)', "a'a a & a (Also yyyy) (a, a) ", 'a (a, a) (a a)'
```

**Goal:** i want to split but also only when certain character sequences are matched

1. The first split (`first_job`) shall be done after the first `",`  or `',`
2. The second split (`second_job`) shall be done after the second `',`  or first `",`

Conditions:

1. Characters that follow on `(Also`  until `)` (see `xxxx` and `yyyy`above) shall replace the `None` value in `side_job` column
2. The characters that follow on `'Chair,` until the next `',`  shall replace the `None` value in `chair_job` column

This is how the dataframe should look like after a succesful split:

| first_job | second_job | side_job | chair_job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a a (a a), a a | a a, a a, a a (a a), a a a a (a, a a) a a, a a, a a | xxxx | None |
| a a, a' a | a a, a 5 (a, a) a a | None | None |
| a (a a) (a, a) | a'a a & a (a, a) a (a, a) (a a) | yyyy | Chair, a (a & a), a a, a, Chair, a, a & a-a - a -a |

The problem is also that i am really new to regex as i have tried avoid using it in the past. I think for this task `re.split()` can be used, right, as i am not going to split on zero widths?

I have come so far as to split on either double or single quotes

```
re.split(r"'(?=,)|"(?=,)"
```

but i am far away from doing the above.

Comment: You're really looking for a small parser here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your example columns, I don't know of a 'clean' regex only solution. You need to both extract and remove your matches ("substitute with nothing").

I would recommend using an [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) based solution. This allows you to use a function to capture the pretty complex logic you need for your data cleanup.

We can also make use of the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to substitute any matches of the `(Also \w)` pattern with nothing.

Here is a quick example of how these might work together (but by no means perfect):

```py
import pandas as pd
import re


a = '- a a (a a), a a', '- a a (Also xxxx), a a', '- a a (a a), a a', 'a a (a, a a)', 'a a, a a', 'a a'       
b =   "a a, a' a", 'a a, a 5 (a, a)', 'a a'                                                               
c =  'Chair, a (a & a), a a, a', 'Chair, a, a & a-a - a -a' 'a (a a) (a, a)', "a'a a & a (Also yyyy) (a, a) ", 'a (a, a) (a a)'


df = pd.DataFrame({"split_these_jobtitles": [a, b, c]})
print(df["split_these_jobtitles"])


def extract_jobs(row):
    # Store a short temporary variable name
    split_text = row["split_these_jobtitles"]

    # Compile a regex to find the side_job and find it
    match_side_job = re.compile(r"\(Also (?P<side_job>\w*?)\)")
    side_job = match_side_job.search(" ".join(split_text))
    side_job = side_job.groupdict("side_job")["side_job"] if side_job else None # ensure None if no matches

    # Get the chair job and remove it from our options
    chair_jobs = [txt for txt in split_text if txt.startswith("Chair,")]
    chair_jobs = chair_jobs if chair_jobs else None # ensure None if no chair jobs
    split_text = [txt for txt in split_text if txt not in chair_jobs]

    # Remove any side_job matches from the split_text list
    split_text = [match_side_job.sub("", txt) for txt in split_text]

    first_job = split_text[0]
    second_job = split_text[1]
    return first_job, second_job, side_job, chair_jobs


df[["first_job", "second_job", "side_job", "chair_jobs"]] = df.apply(
    lambda row: extract_jobs(row), axis="columns", result_type="expand"
)
print(df)
```

This gives me the following:

```
0    (- a a (a a), a a, - a a (Also xxxx), a a, - a...
1                    (a a, a' a, a a, a 5 (a, a), a a)
2    (Chair, a (a & a), a a, a, Chair, a, a & a-a -...
Name: split_these_jobtitles, dtype: object
                               split_these_jobtitles           first_job       second_job side_job                                         chair_jobs
0  (- a a (a a), a a, - a a (Also xxxx), a a, - a...    - a a (a a), a a      - a a , a a     xxxx                                                 []
1                  (a a, a' a, a a, a 5 (a, a), a a)           a a, a' a  a a, a 5 (a, a)     None                                                 []
2  (Chair, a (a & a), a a, a, Chair, a, a & a-a -...  a'a a & a  (a, a)    a (a, a) (a a)     yyyy  [Chair, a (a & a), a a, a, Chair, a, a & a-a -...
```

For help with regex, I would suggest sites like https://www.debuggex.com/ and https://regex101.com/. To help you visualise what is going on and understand some of the common "tokens".

Credit to [@samusa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66736464/7724187) for the earlier answer of the regex pattern for "side_job"

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your task. Splitting every line makes sense. To get the Chair and side job within brackets, I can suggest these regex:

```
match_side_job = re.search(r'\(Also (?P<side_job>\w*?)\)')
match_chair =  re.search(r'?P<chair>Chair.*?),')
 
match_side_job.groupdict('side_job')
yyyyy
match_chair.groupdict('chair')
Chair abcde
```

propably only applied to parts of the splitted lines.